# Not able to pass value from thickbox popup to parent page

Tags: javascript, forms, thickbox

I have an iframe popup with thickbox:

```
<a href="popupPage.jsp?keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=250&width=400" title="adis" class="thickbox">Example 1</a>
```

This is opening nice. In the popup I have 1 textbox and the value from this textbox must be copied into the textbox on the parent JSP page.

I tried several things like

```
function update() {
    window.opener.document.getElementById('txtBox1').value= 'Test'; 
}
```

but it does not work.

Do you know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Adidas: Assuming you're using ThickBox with jQuery, in `popupPage.jsp` you could try --

```
function update() {
    $('#txtBox1', top.document).val('Test');
}
```

...to set the value for the parent document's input.

Comment: ow my god... i spent hours looking for this and tried using the top.document in a wrong way!!! But you gave me a superior answer! Thank you soooo much!! it is working now with: top.document.getElementById('userCostCentre').value=document.getElementById('field1').value;